# Access denied to visit a site without www

Tags: dns, no-www, 403-forbidden

Why can I visit my own site: `http://www.example.com` but not `http://example.com`, which gives me

> HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden): The server refused to fulfill the request

How do it fix it?

I wrote the site and upload to remote server.

Comment: Is it your own site or some other site? E.g. are you asking how can you fix this on your web server, or just want to know why it happens while you're browsing the web?

Comment: You have to configure the server for both but 'how' really depends on depends on your set. You really have to give more information.

Comment: If you're able to edit your DNS records, the simplest fix is to set the naked domain A-record (not www) to the IP on here: http://wwwizer.com/ which will automagically redirect visitors without the www, to the www. Alternatively you need to make rewrite rules, but I don't think you're using Apache, so more details are helpful.

Comment: I don't have my own server but uploading to a 3rd party hosting service.

Comment: Please use the [RFC2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606)-mandated `example.com` domain in questions.

Answer (score 2):

mickburkejnr is close, but not entirely right. The problem is not with DNS (it *could* be, but that's unlikely). The problem is that your web server isn't configured to respond to queries for your site without the "www" prefix with the appropriate site.

Keep in mind that "www" is just a normal subdomain. "google.com" is the root site, "www.google.com" is a subdomain, just like "mail.google.com" is. If you wanted "mail.google.com" and "google.com" to go to the same place, then you'd have tell your webserver that.

Generally, the best solution is to redirect from "www" to the non-www version of the site (some prefer the other way; as you can see, SE sites don't). You can find examples of how to do that with common webservers easily using Google.

With Apache, I like to simply use the redirect directive in a separate virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Server www.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: +1 And I added a non-redirecting alternative configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You DNS record isn't set up to accept traffic to the server without the `www`. This is a simple A record, and all it will contain is either a blank space or "my0wnsite.com".

If you can't change the DNS records yourself, contact either your registrar or your hosting company and they will sort this out fairly quickly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's diagnosis is correct. I will offer another server configuration which serves a slightly different function than Tom's:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Tom's configuration will cause the server to *redirect* www.example.com to example.com and then serve content, whereas the above configuration will *serve the same content without redirecting*.

Comment: Why the downvote?